# I am not able to gray-out resources which are outside start and end date

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, angular14

I want to grayout other date which is not between in **businessHours**. In this example I've passed in resource **a** businessHours dates. I want a grayout background of before 2024-01-19 and after 2024-01-30 dates. So I am not able to drop any event before and after this dates.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: [
      {
        "id": "a",
        "title": "Auditorium A",
        businessHours: {
          start: new Date('2024-01-19'),
          end: new Date('2024-01-30')
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "b",
        "title": "Auditorium B",
        "eventColor": "green"
      },
      {
        "id": "c",
        "title": "Auditorium C",
        "eventColor": "orange"
      }
    ],
    events: [
      {
        "resourceId": "b",
        "title": "event 5",
        "start": "2024-01-19T10:00:00+00:00",
        "end": "2024-01-19T15:00:00+00:00"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "a",
        "title": "event 2",
        "start": "2024-01-19T09:00:00+00:00",
        "end": "2024-01-19T14:00:00+00:00"
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

[image]

Comment: `businessHours` not `bussinessHours`. Then it works fine: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNRmdRb . Always double-check your work carefully. Voting to close the question as caused by a typo

Comment: Yes sorry that was a spell mistake in description but in code that was a right spell. I want a grayout background in dayscale as well @ADyson

Comment: As my CodePen demo shows, it will already grey out in the day view as well, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I need in month view not day view

Comment: In my uploaded image you can see that was a 3 month duration I need in this view not hourly scale view

Comment: Ok. Well you can set the view and the slot duration however you wish. But that has nothing to do with setting businessHours and disallowing dragging, and it has nothing to do with the background events solution you've put in the answer below, either. So I'm not sure what your point is? You said `I want a grayout background in dayscale as well`, so I pointed out that businessHours will already do that in the "day" view. Now you say you only want a 3 month view...make up  your mind!

Comment: Sorry @ADyson for misunderstanding. My point was dayscale not day view you can pass the duration businessHours was working with only hourlyscale not in dayscale. You can see my ticket in github ticket using below link https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7576 this was resolve by full calendar support team

Comment: Also you can see my image in this image you can not see any hours in calendar. that was a complete day so businessHours was working with only hourly scale.

Comment: By `dayscale` do you mean setting a `slotDuration` to a different value? I am not understanding that terminology, it is not wording used in the fullCalendar documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all of you for giving your time to resolve this but I got a solution from Fullcalendar support team which is below,

I've added background-events based on my resource availability like

```
events.push({
   id: 'my-resource-id',
   start: new Date('2024-01-01'),
   end: new Date('2024-03-15'),
   rendering: 'inverse-background',
   resourceId: 'my-resource-id',
   backgroundColor: 'gray'
})
```

In my data Cornelia and Monika was not available from 15th March and I got below output which I want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use datesSet callback in FullCalendar to dynamically update the background rendering of the calendar based on the conditions.

Add a function to in the same like I did below. Change the dates as you need.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: [
      {
        "id": "a",
        "title": "Auditorium A",
        businessHours: {
          start: new Date('2024-01-19'),
          end: new Date('2024-01-30')
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "b",
        "title": "Auditorium B",
        "eventColor": "green"
      },
      {
        "id": "c",
        "title": "Auditorium C",
        "eventColor": "orange"
      }
    ],
    events: [
      {
        "resourceId": "b",
        "title": "event 5",
        "start": "2024-01-19T10:00:00+00:00",
        "end": "2024-01-19T15:00:00+00:00"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "a",
        "title": "event 2",
        "start": "2024-01-19T09:00:00+00:00",
        "end": "2024-01-19T14:00:00+00:00"
      }
    ],
    datesSet: function (info) {
      var startDate = info.start.toISOString().split('T')[0];
      var endDate = info.end.toISOString().split('T')[0];

      calendarEl.querySelectorAll('.fc-day').forEach(function (cell) {
        var cellDate = cell.getAttribute('data-date');
        if (cellDate < '2024-01-19' || cellDate > '2024-01-30') {
          cell.classList.add('fc-non-business');
        } else {
          cell.classList.remove('fc-non-business');
        }
      });
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Try this and let me know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: my resource data was dynamic for an example Angela was available only from 22nd Jan 2024 to 26th Jan 2024 also another resources has different different dates which comes from API. so in datesSet function we can't not identify which specific resource dates was rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Bhavy . I got a solution from Fullcalendar support team thank youu!!